# Customizing datepickerdialog in fragmnets

Tags: android

Can anyone please let me know how can set the selected date on DatePickerDialog i.e if i select the date and when i open the dapickerdialog again it should show that selcted date instead of current date.
And also how can i disable the other years from the datepickerdialog i.e only current year and coming year date will be selectable only .
If there are any library suggestion that i can use please let me know.

I have searched a lot but no one fulfill my requirement.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It may help you try the below code and alter according to your recruitment

```
public class TodayTabFragment extends Fragment {
    Activity mActivity;
    SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mActivity=getActivity();
        mSharedPreferences= mActivity.getSharedPreferences("selected_date", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_fragment_today_layout, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        final SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
        try {
            Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            int YEAR=mSharedPreferences.getInt("year",0);
            if (YEAR==0)
                YEAR=mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int MONTH=mSharedPreferences.getInt("monthOfYear",0);
            if (MONTH==0)
                MONTH=mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int DAY_OF_MONTH=mSharedPreferences.getInt("dayOfMonth",0);
            if (DAY_OF_MONTH==0)
               DAY_OF_MONTH=mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(mActivity, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                    newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putInt("year", year);
                    editor.putInt("monthOfYear", monthOfYear);
                    editor.putInt("dayOfMonth", dayOfMonth);
                    editor.apply();
                    System.out.print(dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime()));
                }

            }, YEAR, MONTH, DAY_OF_MONTH);
            DatePicker datePicker = datePickerDialog.getDatePicker();
            Date minDate = dateFormatter.parse((YEAR-1)+"-"+MONTH+"-"+DAY_OF_MONTH);
            datePicker.setMinDate(minDate.getTime());
            Date maxDate = dateFormatter.parse((YEAR+1)+"-"+MONTH+"-"+DAY_OF_MONTH);
            datePicker.setMaxDate(maxDate.getTime());
            datePickerDialog.show();
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.printStackTrace(e);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi , thanks for your response but how do i disable the future years from the calendar and set the selected date on datepicker on next open

Comment: no, not working. Using dtaepickerdialog in fragments

Comment: Check out your code .. I just tried myself in fragment.. its working fine for me..I Just update disabling date below one year and after one year. Change the condition according to your requirement.

Comment: no, its not working showing same result ,even changes the datepicker UI  i.e showing a seperate header on the datepicker.